# How to use key vault secret on Powershell that run on DevOps pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

everyone,

There are 2 tasks in my DevOps pipeline, the first is for getting the secret value from Azure Key Vault,

```
trigger: none
jobs: 
- job: PBICDSolution
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest

  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '<my subscription>'
      KeyVaultName: 'PA01'
      SecretsFilter: '<my secret name>'
      RunAsPreJob: false
```

Next I want to use this secret value inside my powershell script for login a service principal account. Here is my powershell code,

```
$azureAplicationId = "<my service principal client id>"
$azureTenantId= "<my tanant id>"

Write-Output "Generate Credential"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString <here should be the variable of AKV secret value> -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)

Write-Output "Login SP"
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Tenant $azureTenantId -ServicePrincipal -Credential $psCred
```

Here is the pipeline yml code for above task,

```
  - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '<my subscripton name>'
      ScriptType: 'FilePath'
      ScriptPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\<my ps file name>.ps1'
      ScriptArguments: '<how can i set the variable here?>'
      azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

So the question is here, **how can I get the output value from task1, then pass this value into task2** (PowerShell script)?
I have refer to [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops) but it's not helpful since I don't need to download the secret to a txt file.

Any solution would be grateful!

Comment: I am not very known with Azure as we have our own pipeline (and vault). Nevertheless I am structing with similar questions for a long time now. The Azure docs you refer to say: `script: 'echo $(Your-Secret-Name) > secret.txt`, which is -I guess- plain text, or? So I agree, you should actually secure that, but than, a [**SecureString shouldn't be used**](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md); ***The general approach of dealing with credentials is to avoid them and instead rely on other means to authenticate, such as certificates or Windows authentication.***.

Comment: But what if that is that isn't feasible or just easer said then done for your environment? I came up with a `SecureString` wrapper in the form of an [`HiddenString`](https://github.com/iRon7/HiddenString) which -as the name implies- has a slightly different purpose, see also: [`#16921` Add `HiddenString` Class](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16921). But still not sure whether this is the answer to this dilemma...

Answer (score 3):

> how can I get the output value from task1, then pass this value into task2 (PowerShell script)?

The key vault you downloaded in the azure key vault task can be used as a Pipeline variable.

Refer to the following steps to use the Key vault.

In Azure Powershell Task, you can define the arguement: `-azurePassword  $(azurePassword)`

For example:

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: FilePath'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: xx
    ScriptPath: test.ps1
    ScriptArguments: '-azurePassword  $(azurePassword)'
    preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: 3.1.0
```

In Powershell file, you can define the param.

For example:

```
param (
  
  [string]$azurePassword
)
```

Comment: I get an error.The term '***' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot Kevin Lu-MSFT